# Regex bank account balance using selenium in python

Tags: python, regex, selenium

I am working on a Python3 program that uses Selenium to open a web browser in Chrome then navigates to the Bank of America account information page. However, I am having trouble with extracting the actual account balance from a string that contains a dollar sign.

I want to extract the value from the account balance and store the number without the dollar sign. How would I do this?

```
from selenium import webdriver
... # Logins in & navigates to account info
balanceValue = browser.find_element_by_class_name('AccountBalance')
balanceValue = balanceValue.text


print(balanceValue)
$415.24

# I want the following output without the dollar sign
print(balanceValue)
415.24
```

Comment: `balanceValue[1:]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to use the regular expression to extract the value, you can use the below.

```
import re
match = re.search("\d+\.\d*","$123.45")
value = match.group(0)
```

This will make sure even if your output have space between the dollar symbol and value like `$ 123.45`. In this case the `[1:]` approach will give you the incorrect information. And you can use this regular expression against any currency eg: `Rs.123.45`

[image]

If you want to simplify it you can do

```
value = re.search("\d+\.\d*","$123.45")[0]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I tried re.search() before but could not extract the match group.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `lstrip` to strip a character from the left side of a string:

```
>>> balance = '$415.24'
>>> balance_value = balance.lstrip('$')
>>> print(balance_value)
415.24
```